# Is it possible to flatten an array that is 700 000 entries long without exceeding the call stack?

Tags: javascript, arrays, callstack

I am trying to flatten a huge array that consists of 100 000 items, I am flattening it twice because it is 2d and I want to get all objects inside the 2nd arrays:
`[ [ {} ] ]`

What I have tried is using reduce and using concat, like this:

**Concat.** firstFlat is processed within a second. secondFlat causes the max call stack to be exceeded.

```
let firstArray = Array(100000).fill(Array(7).fill({}));
let firstFlat = [].concat.apply([], firstArray);
let secondFlat = [].concat.apply([], firstFlat);
```

**Reduce.** The call stack is also exceeded

```
let array = Array(100000).fill(Array(7).fill({}))
                         .reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y))
                         .reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y))
                         .reduce((x, y) => x.concat(y));
```

I can't think of a solution, probably because I don't quite get what the call stack is exactly. I know that it's the 'stack' of all functions currently being executed. But shouldn't reduce be only 1 function? And the anonymous function inside is executed once, and then the anonymous function is used with other arguments. So there should be a 1 reduce function on the callstack and 1 anonymous function. So how does it exceed the call stack? The only reason I can think of is that reduce is a function loop, I don't know how to call it, but like I mean this: function a() { a() }, which it probably is. In that case I would be better off using forEach/for. But then why does the first method exceed the callstack? Concat is just one function as well right? I'm so confused.

I would really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance

Edit: The same issue seems to be happening with Object.assign. All of these functions rely on function loops. I think it should be updated so they use async await instead, so the call stack doesn't fill

Comment: +1 since I would also like to know about the reduce function on the callstack. If it would be 100000 times on the callstack i could also go with a for loop implementation.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I just tested it and it seems like it's only on the callstack once, both reduce and the anonymous function inside reduce. [Screenshot](https://gyazo.com/3b82fe01ffeb6869a1f745961a6d269b). This is so weird!

Comment: Can you please post the exact error messages? I can't believe the second snippet overflows the call stack.

Comment: I don't get why you would flatten it twice (or even thrice in the `reduce` snippet!). It's an array of arrays (of objects), and you want an array (of objects). That's *one* level of flattening, from 2D to 1D.

Comment: "*The same issue seems to be happening with Object.assign. All of these functions rely on function loops. I think it should be updated so they use async await instead, so the call stack doesn't fill*" - that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can just use [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest you to use the spreading operator. More "powerful".

```
let firstArray = Array(100000).fill(Array(7).fill({}));
Array.prototype.concat(...firstArray) // (700000) [...]
```

The first flattening step comes with the usage of spread operator.

After "translating" the spread operator, it does something like this :

```
Array.prototype.concat(firstArray[0], firstArray[1], ..., firstArray[699999]);
```

And this is the second level of flattening.

Comment: That would still exceed the maximum stack size when flattening twice :P I think I'll just use loops for now

Comment: Don't understand, you get the flattened Array of 700 000 items at the first call. Or I didn't understrand your question.

Comment: Ah nevermind! I thought you flattened it once, but you used ... ofc. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MathRobin Could you please explain what `...` does different than `apply`, and why that would reduce the number of arguments on the stack?

Comment: Don't know for the theory behind this. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

OP here, My theory about reduce being a 'convenience loop function' was right, which was quite clear tbh. This is processed within a second:

```
firstArray = Array(100000).fill(Array(7).fill({}));
let list = [];
for(let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++)
    for(let j = 0; j < firstArray[i].length; j++) 
        list.push(firstArray[i][j]);
```

Good luck with your project (if anybody needed this :))

@MathRobin posted a better solution, check that one out :P